# Can't delete the record in database/access from vb form

Tags: vb.net, function, rows, delete-row

I'm trying to do a to do list program, but my remove button is not working. Here is my remove button:

```
    Private Sub btnremove_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnremove.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to remove this task?", _
        "Remove", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
        MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.No Then

        MsgBox("Operation Cancelled")
        Exit Sub
    End If
   Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    con.Open()
    ds.Tables("todolist").Rows(inc).Delete()
    MaxRows = MaxRows - 1
    ds.AcceptChanges()
    con.Close()
    inc = 0
    NavigateRecords()
    da.Update(ds, "todolist")


End Sub
```

After I press the remove button, it will only remove from my user interface, but not in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Private Sub btnremove_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnremove.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to remove this task?", _
        "Remove", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, _
        MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.No Then
        MsgBox("Operation Cancelled")
    Else
        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        con.Open()
        ds.Tables("todolist").Rows(inc).Delete()
        MaxRows = MaxRows - 1
        ds.AcceptChanges()
        con.Close()
        inc = 0
        NavigateRecords()
        da.Update(ds, "todolist")
    End If
End Sub
```

NOTE : the msgbox's default button is `NO` if you press `NO` it wont delete the Entry when msgbox prompt  `press YES` then the code will pass into delete section then only it will remove from `DB`

try this if not works come back

Comment: Still the same, it only delete it in interface but when I go to my another form with datagrid I pressed refresh still the same data. @LifeRunsOnCode

Comment: what you  press when `msgbox` ask `Do you really want to remove this task?`  `YES/NO` ?

Comment: I press `YES` then it will return me to the interface and the record is not at the interface anymore then I go to my summary interface it will still there @LifeRunsOnCode

Comment: ok so when you press `YES` then the code will hit the `else` condition right ?

Comment: I've found the solution which is add `cb.QuotePrefix = "[" and cb.QuotePrefix = "]"` below the commandbuilder